# How to start out in blender?

Tags: modeling

I am new to this amazing world of 3D modeling. I wanted to know how can I start 3D modeling from scratch? I am very new to this,I googled up and found that blender is a nice software for 3D modeling and its free too, so I decided to work onto this.

I wanna know is there any background required for learning 3D modeling or anyone(having some prior interest) can start up with this.

well I have some programming experience in C, C++, C#, and python, so am I set with that to learn 3D modeling or do i need to gather some more knowledge or experience in any other field.

From where should I start?

Comment: StackExchange is more for specific questions which have specific answers, I suggest you rather ask on blenderartists.org to get a better response.

Comment: And why do I get a -1 for answering it?

Comment: We have a collection of beginner resources here: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40/beginners-reference

Answer (score 4):

You could go to [Blender Guru](http://www.blenderguru.com/) for some tutorials; Also there's [CG Cookie](https://cgcookie.com/).

Answer (score 4):

As someonewithpc said [BlenderGuru.com](http://BlenderGuru.com) is a really good place to start. That's where I learned most of Blender.

There are a bunch of tutorials and videos out there: [BlenderCookie](http://cgcookie.com/blender), [BlenderDiplom](http://www.blenderdiplom.com), [BlenderArtist(forum)](http://blenderartists.org/forum/), etc.

Hope that will at least get you started.

Answer (score 3):

There are no prerequisites to learning blender. There are other things you will want to learn in the future, but to just start out in blender no previous experience is required.
Since you are brand new to blender, I would recommend [cg cookies' blender basics](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL9057AB8E3C66AE80).